# How to handle localization of controller names?

Tags: zend-framework, localization

I run a site where it is important to have good and simple URLs that need to be localized.

Example for the english version:
example.com/car/?type=fiat

Example for the Swedish version:
example.se/bil/?typ=fiat (bil is car in swedish)

And ofcourse I would like to handle all of these URLs from the same codebase. What is the best way to handle this?

Should I set up several controllers (CarController, BilController) or is there a "cleaner" way to handle localized controller names?

BR
Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about rewriting the URL depending on the domain? This way, the Zend framework will get only the English names, while the URL can use localized names.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something along these lines. Is there any standardized way to do this or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: @Niklas How did u end up solving the problem. I thought about the same problem. Moreover I think it is necessary to add the language to the url e.g. /en/car or /de/auto/ or /all_sv/. Any hints how you solved the international localized urls with zend router?

Comment: You also need to localize the urls when building the site and the layout. eg. $this->url("controler"=>"car", "lang"=>"de"); how did u solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Ever.

Microsoft, a really big, powerful and resourceful company tried that with Excel. In English versions of Excel, you use `IF()` in formulas. In the German version, it's `WENN()`. In French, it's `QUAND()`, I think. In Japan, it's probably `ば()`. Now imagine someone from Japan sends me an Excel sheet ... There are two options:

1. "I'm sorry, I can't open this file"
2. Translate all names on the fly

Doing #2 seems simple enough ... until you run into a word which uses the same letters but has a different meaning in two languages. Example "see". Means "look" in English and "lake" in German. Since you don't know all the languages in the world, you have no chance to figure out which collisions you will have before it is too late.

Also, how do you know which name to use? From the language in the browser? Or do you hate your international customers who occasionally use the Swedish main site? How do you handle Asian languages? Will the URL be `server/%E6%AC%80%E6/?%AD%81%E6%AB=fiat`?

Don't. Do. That. Ever.

Comment: I'm not trying to make excel so this does not really apply. Also, the site will be localized anyway so there will be different versions of it.